# How to draw a type-inference parse tree for sml

Tags: sml

So I am working on my practice final, there is problem ask me to draw a parse tree for this sml code:

```
fun ff f x y = if (f x y) then (f 3 y) else (f x "zero")

val ff = fn : (int -> string -> bool) -> int -> string -> bool
```

I understand how to get this type but not so sure how to draw a parse tree to represent it.

For my homework we did do question like this which is way simpler :
[image for my other homework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPg5q.png)

Comment: Excuse the shameless plug, but take a look at this presentation of mine, it might help you. https://speakerdeck.com/igstan/a-type-inferencer-for-ml-in-200-lines-of-scala Also, two videos on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPVTNxiMcSU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7x4THVU4BQ

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of is to slightly reformat your code and basically put each subexpression on its own line. Children are denoted by increased indentation.

Let's take your example:

```
fun ff f x y = if (f x y) then (f 3 y) else (f x "zero")
```

First, we need to do a little desugaring. The above is equivalent to this:

```
val ff =
  fn f =>
    fn x =>
      fn y =>
        if (f x y) then (f 3 y) else (f x "zero")
```

Now, let's put each subexpression on its own line (the parantheses are redundant in this particular example; everything works fine without them):

```
val ff =
  fn f =>
    fn x =>
      fn y =>
        if
          f
            x
              y
          then
            f
              3
                y
          else
            f
              x
                "zero"
```

Finally, let's attach a type to each subexpression, but let's use type variables for types we don't know yet. Notice we're using the same type variables for the same occurrences. For example `x` has type `t3` everywhere.

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | t1 -> t2
    fn x =>            | t3 -> t4
      fn y =>          | t5 -> t6
        if             | t7 (* the type of the whole `if` expression *)
          f            | t1
            x          | t3
              y        | t5
          then         | t8 (* the type of the whole `then` part *)
            f          | t1
              3        | int
                y      | t5
          else         | t9 (* the type of the whole `else` part *)
            f          | t1
              x        | t3
                "zero" | string
```

You can then do some further simplifications by noticing that some type variables are equivalent or that they're used in certain contexts. For example, from these three calls to `f`:

- `f x y`
- `f 2 y`
- `f x "zero"`

we can gather that `x` must be of type `int` and `y` must be of type `string`. So, let's replace the type of `x`, that is `t3`, with `int`, and the type of `y`, that is `t5`, with `string`. We do this everywhere:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | t1 -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> t4
      fn y =>          | string -> t6
        if             | t7
          f            | t1
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | t8
            f          | t1
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | t9
            f          | t1
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

Also, `f` is used as a function that is being passed an `int` each time. The result is also used as a function and is being passed a `string`. That means `t1`, which is the type variable assigned to `f`, must be of type `int -> string -> r0`, for some `r0` we don't know yet. Let's replace all occurrences of `t1` with `int -> string -> r0`.

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> r0) -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> t4
      fn y =>          | string -> t6
        if             | t7
          f            | int -> string -> r0
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | t8
            f          | int -> string -> r0
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | t9
            f          | int -> string -> r0
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

But notice something, `r0` must be treated as a `bool`, because the result of `f x y` is used in the condition part of an `if` expression, so let's replace `r0` with `bool` everywhere:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> t4
      fn y =>          | string -> t6
        if             | t7
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | t8
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | t9
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

Next, the type of the whole `if` expression must be the same as the type of the `then` part, which must be the same as the type of the `else` part. So `t7`, `t8` and `t9` must all be the same. Let's use `t7` where we see `t8` and `t9`.

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> t4
      fn y =>          | string -> t6
        if             | t7
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | t7
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | t7
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

Next, `t7` must be of type `bool` because the type of both `f 3 y` and `f x "zero"` is `bool`:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> t4
      fn y =>          | string -> t6
        if             | bool
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

Next, `t6` must be a `bool` too, because we're returning the result of the `if` expression:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> t4
      fn y =>          | string -> bool
        if             | bool
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

Next, `t4` must be of type `string -> bool`, because that's what the type of its body is:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> t2
    fn x =>            | int -> string -> bool
      fn y =>          | string -> bool
        if             | bool
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

What's `t2`? It must be the type of the body, which is `int -> string -> bool`:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | t0
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> int -> string -> bool
    fn x =>            | int -> string -> bool
      fn y =>          | string -> bool
        if             | bool
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

Finally, the type `t0` of `ff` must be equal with the type of the value assigned to `ff`. So:

```
Subexpression          | Type
---------------------- | ------------------------------------------
val ff =               | (int -> string -> bool) -> int -> string -> bool
  fn f =>              | (int -> string -> bool) -> int -> string -> bool
    fn x =>            | int -> string -> bool
      fn y =>          | string -> bool
        if             | bool
          f            | int -> string -> bool
            x          | int
              y        | string
          then         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              3        | int
                y      | string
          else         | bool
            f          | int -> string -> bool
              x        | int
                "zero" | string
```

And that's your final result.